# SimpleXMLElement: Retrieving Namespace Attribute

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml

I've read about hundreds of SO-entries about that, but I can't get it to work. I can't really see what I'm doing wrong. I'm most certainly doing something obviously stupid, but at the moment I can't see it.

I'm trying to parse http://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1/shops/614852/productTypes?locale=de_DE&fullData=false&limit=20&offset=0

This is what I'm doing:

```
$shopUrl = "http://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1/shops/614852/productTypes?".
    "locale=de_DE&fullData=false&limit=20&offset=0"


$ch = curl_init($shopUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    

$products = new SimpleXMLElement($result);  

foreach ($products->productType as $product) {
    $resources = $product->children('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
    $resEntity = array(
        'id' => (int)$product->attributes()->id,
        'name' => (string)$product->name[0],
        'price' => (string)$product->price[0]->vatIncluded[0],
        'preview' => $resources
    );
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($resEntity, true).'</pre>';    
}
```

This outputs me

```
Array
(
    [id] => 6
    [name] => Männer T-Shirt klassisch
    [price] => 9.90
    [preview] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [href] => http://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1/shops/614852/productTypes/6
                )

        )

)
```

I'm now trying to access the HREF-attribute but everything I've tried so far like `$resources->attributes()->href` or `$resources['href']` but PHP keeps on saying `Node no longer exists`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the namespace in the `attributes()` method. I guess (it's not explained in detail in the manual of [`attributes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)) you have to specify the xml namespace with the first argument. This might get you the `href` attribute from the `xlink` namespace. Otherwise you just get the attributes from the *default* xml namespace, namely `type` and `mediaType` (or from which node you fetch the attributes).

It should be work like this (not tested):

```
$resources = $product->resources[0];   // <resources> node
$resource = $resources->resource[0];   // first <resource> node
$attribs = $resource->attributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');   // fetch all attributes from the given namespace
var_dump($attribs->href);   // or maybe var_dump((string)$attribs->href);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm. `'preview' => (string)$attribs->href[0]`